# How to redirect from url parameters in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a download page on my wordpress site.
I want to pass in a url like `http://www.mypersonaldomain.com/download?url=http://link.to/the.pdf`

I would like it to wait 3 seconds or so, thanking them for downloading.

I have tried some php and meta tags and neither seemed to work well in wordpress.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=<%out.print(request.getParameter("url"))%>">
```

and using a php insert plugin

```
[insert_php]
$url= $_GET['url'];  
header("refresh:3;url=$url" );
[/insert_php]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Condition Start $url = 'http://www.mypersonaldomain.com/download?url=http//link.to/the.pdf'wp_redirect( $url);exit;/ Condition End
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the wp_redirect part will be useful, but the portion of the URL i am interseted in stripping would be "http://link.to/the.pdf"